Recutils not compiling due to errors, which appear to be warnings
Recutils fails to build on my linux arch system. It appears the same on all of my machines which are also running Arch Linux. I have updated my pacman and run ldconfig as instructed by some post I have seen on the Ubuntu help pages. Additionally, I have tried to build the version from the AUR with the same result. I am trying to build version 1.9. ./configure does report an issue with libmdb not installed, but I believe it should still build without it.
I believed, I may have mistakenly modified the /etc/makepkg on my system, so I removed it and re-installed pacman. I believe there is no make.conf to tinker with on an Arch Linux setup.
The rectuils help forum kindly provided a comparison of the build logs. It appears my errors halt the build but this does not happen on Debian or Ubuntu machines as per the other log.
This is part of my log:
rec-sex-parser.c:68:7: error: implicit declaration of function 'sexlex_init' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
68 |       sexlex_init (&(new->scanner));
>        |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
rec-sex-parser.c:69:7: error: implicit declaration of function 'sexset_extra' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
69 |       sexset_extra (new, new->scanner);
>        |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
rec-sex-parser.c: In function 'rec_sex_parser_destroy':
rec-sex-parser.c:86:7: error: implicit declaration of function 'sexlex_destroy' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
86 |       sexlex_destroy (parser->scanner);
>        |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1854: rec-sex-parser.lo] Error 1

This is the same part from a working Debian machine, provided by the help forum:
rec-sex-parser.c:53:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sexlex_init' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    53 |       sexlex_init (&(new->scanner));
       |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
rec-sex-parser.c:54:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sexset_extra' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    54 |       sexset_extra (new, new->scanner);
       |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
rec-sex-parser.c: In function 'rec_sex_parser_destroy':
rec-sex-parser.c:70:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sexlex_destroy' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    70 |     sexlex_destroy (parser->scanner); 

I tried to modify the config file in the AUR version to ignore errors using the -k or -Wall/Werror flags as well as running the ./configure command with CCFLAGS=-Wall
As you can see from the above. I am out of my depth. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If there is a compiler warning, fix it, because there are good chances that tomorrow it will become an error (and for you, the tomorrow comes today). Demo. The only sane way to deal with the problem is to fix it upstream. There should be no warnings, full stop, no ifs or buts.

I agree the warnings should be fixed but no doubt the difference in behavior is due to either a different version of GCC, or different compiler flags.  Newer versions of GCC may have use different standards as the default if you don't provide one, which means different things are considered errors vs. warnings.  if you don't want any warnings to be treated as errors add the -Wno-error option to your compile line.

Please note, You should pass "CFLAGS=-Wall" to ./configure, not CCFLAGS... in order to override the flags passed to the C compiler for compiling the parser. The proper fix, as said would be to fix upstream -- by declaring the functions in a separate header-file, probably rec-sex-parser.h.
